# Unit testing MVC EditorTemplates through EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have some html extension methods, that use EditorFor to render content based on different EditorTemplates (views). I need to unit test these extension methods, considering also the content rendered from these templates.

I've been searching for hours to find a way to make it happen, but I could not find any. Is there a way to do so, or I should try to unit test these views separately?

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string templateName, object additionalViewData);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073103/how-to-unit-test-an-extension-method-that-calls-html-editorfor